# I have an error making buttons in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord-buttons

I have a problem, when I do a button in discord.js, I always get an error in the console saying: (node:826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

The idea was to click on the button and edit the message, this works very well, but when I use the "defer" so I don't get an error message, it turns out that the command doesn't work right.

```
 const config = require('../config.json')
 const disbut = require("discord-buttons");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
              let embedRp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(' Diversão - [1 Comandos]')
      .setColor(config.embedcolor)
      .setDescription("\> Listei todos os meus comandos de diversão!\n\n• \`/ship\`\n\n**ATENÇÃO:** Está com dúvidas sobre alguns comandos? Se sim, use /info <comando> para saber mais sobre o mesmo.");

              let embedE = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor(' Economia - [0 Comandos]')
      .setColor(config.embedcolor)
      .setDescription("\> Listei todos os meus comandos de Economia!\n\n• \`/Nenhum\`\n\n**ATENÇÃO:** EEstá com dúvidas sobre alguns comandos? Se sim, use /info <comando> para saber mais sobre o mesmo.");

              let embedC = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(' Moderação - [12 Comandos]')
      .setColor(config.embedcolor)
      .setDescription("\> Listei todos os meus comandos de Moderação!\n\n• \`/lock\`, \`/unlock\`, \`/say\`, \`/embed\`, \`/ban\`, \`kick\`, \`/dm\`, \`/unban\`, \`/anunciar\`, \`/clear\`, \`/promover\`, \`/demotar\`\n\n**ATENÇÃO:** Está com dúvidas sobre alguns comandos? Se sim, use /info <comando> para saber mais sobre o mesmo.");

              let embedf = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(' Diversos - [11 Comandos]')
      .setColor(config.embedcolor)
      .setDescription("\> Listei todos os meus comandos Diversos!!\n\n• \`/invite\`, \`/mcavatar\`, \`/mcbody\`, \`/mcskin\`, \`/botinfo\`, \`/ip\`, \`/mcbust\`, \`/mchead\`, \`/sugestão\`, \`/serverinfo\`, \`/info\`\n\n**ATENÇÃO:** Está com dúvidas sobre alguns comandos? Se sim, use /info <comando> para saber mais sobre o mesmo.");

let icon1 = message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 });
    let avatar = message.author.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png'});

let button = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel(' Diversão') 
  .setID('diversao_click')

let button2 = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel(' Economia') 
  .setID('economy_click') 

let button3 = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel(' Moderação') 
  .setID('moderacao_click') 

let button4 = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel(' Diversos') 
  .setID('diversos_click');

let button5 = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('red')
  .setLabel(' Voltar') 
  .setID('home_click');

let row = new disbut.MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(button, button2, button3, button4, button5);

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor('HaveMC - CATEGORIAS')
      .setColor(config.embedcolor)
      .setDescription("• Todos meus comandos disponiveis estão a baixo!!\n\n** - Diversão**\n** - Economia**\n** - Moderação**\n** - Diversos**\n\n**ATENÇÃO:** Está com dúvidas sobre alguns comandos? Se sim, use /info <comando> para saber mais sobre o mesmo.")
      .setThumbnail(icon1);

     let mybuttonsmsg = await message.channel.send(embed, row)
        const collector = mybuttonsmsg.createButtonCollector((button)=> button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, {time: 60e3});
        collector.on("collect", (b) => {
            console.log(b.id)
            if(b.id == "diversao_click"){
                b.defer()
                mybuttonsmsg.edit(embedRp, row)
            }
            else if(b.id == "2"){
                mybuttonsmsg.edit("Testing information message", { buttons: [mybutton] })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You included a shitload ton of irrelevant code. As for the error itself... it simply says `b` is undefined. But that doesn't make sense since it throws an error only when access `b.defer`, despite accessing `b.id` before.. Are you sure you posted the correct code?
Try to include the full stack-trace and highlight the line where the error happens

Answer (score 0):

So after an update, you are required to write the following:

`b.reply.defer()` instead of `b.defer()`.
[Here](https://discord-buttons.js.org/docs/stable/examples/reply.html#defer) is a link to the docs. If there is an error, you can write the collector a little bit differently as an event. Here is the code:

```
const djs = require('discord.js')
const client = new djs.Client()
const disbut = require('discord-buttons')
disbut(client)

client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
if (button.id === "YourID") {
button.reply.defer()
}
})
```

To get an example of an event directly through discord-buttons, check [it here](https://github.com/discord-buttons/discord-buttons/blob/main/index.test.js).